# When MVN INSTALL is executed CPU is going high and leading to PC shutdown

Tags: maven-2

**MVN INSTALL** is causing high CPU and leading to PC shutdown. This is new PC and this is first time I am executing maven commands on this PC. How can I resolve this issue?

Pointed **MAVEN_OPTS** environment variable with below config, still no luck
-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m

changed Icon Overlays to NONE, didnt solve the problem.

[image]

My ***mvn -version*** gives the following...

> Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 00:46:01+0530) Java version:
>   1.8.0_201 Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 10"
>   version: "10.0" arch: "amd64" Family: "dos"

***mvn install*** should not consume high CPU and my PC should not be shut-downed.

Comment: I don't know much about Maven, but the first time executing *any* package manager can surely lead to high load, as it is initializing databases, creating and filling caches, computing dependency trees, etc. Your computer shutting down is not a programming problem, it is a problem with the thermal design of your computer.

Comment: Also, please note that Maven 2.2.1 was released 10 years ago and Maven 2 has reached its end-of-life ages ago.

Comment: Yes, good point. Let me try with latest maven

Comment: I have tried with latest maven it is giving lot of errors. Also in our project 2.2.1 is the certified maven, I have to use that for now. So back to square. For others CPU is not going high, I have checked with them, no differences found. Need to find out which is missing or causing this CPU spike...

Comment: PC shutdown I could stop with this environment variable "MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms128m -Xmx2048m " but CPU high spike issue is still there. Perhaps it would be addressed with latest maven, compatible changes I have to identify and incorporate.